# Redefining the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, lebesgue-measure, determinant

Let $f:E\to E$ be a linear map between an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and itself.

If $\mathcal{B}:=\{\mathbf{e}_1,\dotsc,\mathbf{e}_n\}$ is a basis of $E$, we will say that a linear map $g:E\to E$ is a *type-1* automorphism if there is a $1\leq i\leq n$ and a $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $g(\mathbf{e}_j)=\mathbf{e}_j$ if $j\not=i$ and $g(\mathbf{e}_i)=\lambda\mathbf{e}_i$. Similarly, we will say that $h$ is a *type-2* automorphism if there are $i$,$j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $f(\mathbf{e}_i)=\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_j$ and $f(\mathbf{e}_k)=\mathbf{e}_k$ otherwise.

It is easy to proof that every automorphism can be writen as a composition of several type-1 and type-2 automorphisms with respect to the same basis $\mathcal{B}$. So, lets define $\det(f)$ as the product of the determinants of its decomposition, where $\det(g):=\lambda$ for every type-1 automorphism and $\det(h):=1$ for every type-2 automorphism.

## Question

> How does one prove that the determinant is well defined this way? That is, give two different decompositions of $f$, are both products of determinant the same?

Given that, proving that the determinant has geometric meaning, that is, it does not depend in the chosen basis $\mathcal{B}$ is straightforward.

## Motivation

This definition of determinant is somewhat intuitive, and taylormade to proof a weaker form of the change of variables theorem, which relates the idea of the determinant with the concept of volume. This weaker statement says

> If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set and $f$ is a linear automorphism, the $f(A)$ is Lebesgue-measurable and $\mu(f(A))=\left\lvert\det(f)\right\rvert\mu(A)$.

Comment: I believe you also have to include a type 3 automorphism, which is basically a permutation of the basis elements, and then define the determinant of such an automorphism to be the sign of the permutation. Though I disagree that this is more intuitive, it's definitely an interesting approach :)

Comment: Interestingly, this type-3 automorphism is redundant!

Comment: One way to prove well-definedness would be to note that the determinants of the type-i automorphisms agree with the usual definition of determinant. Further, usual determinant satisfies $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. So this definition of determinant has to agree with the usual one, which is known to be well defined. However, you are perhaps  looking for a direct proof.

Comment: @caffeinemachine yes, I was looking for a proof that does not rely on other usual determinant definitions.